# Stata: svy:mean affecting variable format

Tags: stata

A code I am running uses `svy:mean` and there is NO subpop command used.

My issue is that is that for certain variables, it renames some of the values of the variable to `_subpop_1`, etc. but others are still in their original format. For example, I have a `county` variable. After using the `svy:mean` command, some counties show up as `Alameda`, `Alpine`, etc) while some show up as `_subpop_7`, `_subpop_8`, etc.

Does anyone know why this is?

When using a `tab` command on the same variable, none of the formats are affected and every county shows up.

An example of my code and output (I hid the numbers) would be:

```
foreach var of varlist county {
svy: mean deport, over(`var') 
}

Survey: Mean estimation

Number of strata =       .        Number of obs    =      .
Number of PSUs   =       .        Population size  =      .
                                  Design df        =      .

      ALAMEDA: county = ALAMEDA
       ALPINE: county = ALPINE
       AMADOR: county = AMADOR
        BUTTE: county = BUTTE
    CALAVERAS: county = CALAVERAS
       COLUSA: county = COLUSA
    _subpop_7: county = CONTRA COSTA
    _subpop_8: county = DEL NORTE
    _subpop_9: county = EL DORADO
       FRESNO: county = FRESNO
        GLENN: county = GLENN
     HUMBOLDT: county = HUMBOLDT
     IMPERIAL: county = IMPERIAL
```

Comment: Can you give us code [reproducing your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi, I am using confidential data, so I will give a close example: foreach var of varlist county {svy:mean deport, over('var')}. Then a few lines of the problem output I was describing would be: Alameda: county=Alameda ......._subpop_7: county=Contra Costa

Comment: The example need not use confidential data; just concocted data representative enough to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please read the link provided in my first comment for guidelines on how to provide a reproducible example. Another recommendation is not to post multi-line code in the _comments_ section. You can freely edit your original post and insert it there (with appropriate formatting).

Comment: The issue seems to be the spacing. See `help mean`, the `over()` option: "Noninteger values, negative values, and labels that are not valid Stata names are substituted with a default identifier."

Comment: thanks! I see the issue now. For some reason, the `tab` command does not have an issue with spacing, while `svy:mean` does.

Answer (score 2):

More than a programming problem, this is simply a case of Stata doing what it states it'll do. From `help mean`:

> Noninteger values,
>   negative values, and labels that are not valid Stata names are substituted with a default identifier.

An example reproducing the "problem" is:

```
webuse hbp

// some value labels with spaces
label define lblcity 1 "contra costa" 2 "el dorado" 3 "alameda" 5 "alpine"
label values city lblcity

mean hbp, over(city)
```

More on *valid Stata names* in [[U] 11 Language syntax](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u11.pdf).

(Note the `svy :` prefix plays no role here.)